# Installing modifications on Battle Smith's Steel Defender (5e)

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew, artificer

I'm currently playing an artificer in a homebrew campaign and looking at the SD's stat block, as well as other people's opinions.  It's pretty much just a tank with its damage being negligible at best, so I was wondering if there are any **balanced** homebrew rules someone has made to install modifications on the SD, because that just seems to be the natural thing to do for a class called the Battle *Smith*.  I'm not talking about putting infusions or magic items on the SD, but adding/swapping on its abilities and stats.

Of course my aim isn't to make it OP, but more on to customize how I want it to be as well as make it scale better. I could just talk this out with my DM but I don't want to have her make an entire ruleset on Steel Defender modification from scratch.

Comment: Are you suggesting it isn't already balanced? Or looking to swap AC for damage and similar modifications?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is asking for idea generation. Posting a homebrew proposal for review is within the Stack's limitations; asking for idea generation is not.  For brain storming, I'd recommend [a discussion forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/22566)